# Emacs what modes I am currently using

Tags: emacs

How do I find out what modes are currently running in the current Emacs buffer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can see the major mode and all the minor modes enabled for the selected buffer with:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>
or
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The mode line also displays information about the major mode, and usually some minor modes.

I also recommend you run the tutorial with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, which will teach you a great many useful things.

Comment: You may also be looking for `M-x` `describe-variable` `RET` `major-mode`. Arrived at from [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18084).

Answer (score 2):

Its also useful to learn what all <kbd>C-h</kbd> prefix commands do.

try <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>C-h</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the name that you can add a hook to that mode use C-h v major-mode